# extract data from the given link using php

Tags: php, regex, debugging

I want to extract id from this link and I am trying the following. can anyone guide me whats the mistake

```
$url="https://item.tbao.com/item.htm?id=570147082697";
$regular = '/id\=(.+?)\&/';
preg_match($regular, $url, $data, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
```

I expect to have this 570147082697 but I am not having any output right now.

Comment: The mistake would probably be using regex in the first place, instead of doing a little bit of research what functions might already exist to get the job done. `parse_url` and `parse_str` can easily do this.

Comment: Also, please tag _appropriately_. This has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with `issue tracking`, just because the example URL might be from such a context.

Comment: .+? is lazy matching which means it will get as little as possible. Furthermore \& will try to match & literally but in the url there is no &. If you write your regex like this: /id\=(.+)/ it should be matching the id

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following regex:

```
(?<=id\=).+?(?=\&|$)
```

Details:

- `(?<=id\=).+?`: We get value of param id until before character & or end of line but we don't get string id=
- `(?=\&|$)`: If character is & or end of line

Code to test:

```
//case1: just only id
$url="https://item.tbao.com/item.htm?id=570147082697";
$regular = '/(?<=id\=).+?(?=\&|$)/';
preg_match($regular, $url, $data, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);

echo "case1\n";
print_r($data);

//case2: param id is leading
$url="https://item.tbao.com/item.htm?id=570147082697&test=abc";
$regular = '/(?<=id\=).+?(?=\&|$)/';
preg_match($regular, $url, $data, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);

echo "case2\n";
print_r($data);

//case3: param id is between two params
$url="https://item.tbao.com/item.htm?version=5.1&id=570147082697&test=abc";
$regular = '/(?<=id\=).+?(?=\&|$)/';
preg_match($regular, $url, $data, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);

echo "case3\n";
print_r($data);
```

Result:

```
case1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 570147082697
            [1] => 34
        )

)
case2
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 570147082697
            [1] => 34
        )

)
case3
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 570147082697
            [1] => 46
        )

)
```

I hope my suggestion can help you.

Comment: I think the OP wants the value of the id without the `id=` part looking at the capturing group used in the question.

Comment: @Thefourthbird 
That is my mistake. Thank you for pointing out. I edited my answer. (*ˊᗜˋ*)/ᵗᑋᵃᐢᵏ ᵞᵒᵘ*

Comment: I think `\bid=\K[^&]+(?=&|$)` or `\bid=\K[^&]+` would also do https://regex101.com/r/HlfTKC/1 Note that you don't have to escape the `\=` and the `\&`

Comment: I appreciate your suggested solution. <3